t2g-eg resolved PDOS analysis
I was attempting to analyze the t2g-eg resolved PDOS for transition metal-containing systems. Here, I have taken an example  where three types of transition metals are present in octahedral geometry: $Co^{3+}$ ($t_{2g} ^6 e_g ^0$), $Fe^{3+}$ ($t_{2g} ^3 e_g ^2$), and $Mn^{3+}$ ($t_{2g} ^3 e_g ^1$). As we know, below the Fermi energy ($E_F$), states are occupied, and above it, states are unoccupied. I am puzzled by the observation in the $Co^{3+}$-contained structure, where $e_g$ states are empty, yet there appears to be a significant contribution of occupied states below $E_F$.

I think my answer from that question also pertains here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/12847/4515

Yes it's clear little bit. But I have an one doubt that for example you see in case $Co^{3+}$ where $e_{g}^0$, then below the Fermi level why we are getting non zero area under the curve of $e_g$ just below the $t_{2g}$. I hope you get my point.

@Kratos1611, I have added more detail to my answer in the other question, but fundamentally the same answer applies here. Once ligand bonding and extended bonding are taken into account, there is no fundamental reason that molecular orbitals (or extended bands) with (partial) $e_g$ character could not have same energies as molecular orbitals with partial $t_{2g}$ character. Considering this problem in terms of crystal field theory alone gives incorrect intuition about the problem.
